# JPA EntityTransaction flush

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I would like to flush all the entites stored in the current transaction to the database (without ending the current transaction via commit).

Do I need to check if the transaction is Active before doing so?

```
if (this.entityTransaction.isActive())
   {
      this.entityManager.flush();
   }
```

Thank you

Comment: If you aren't in a transaction for unknown reasons and are making changes that are going to be lost, shouldn't you be throwing an exception anyway?

Comment: @Chris You sir...got a point. But what does "isActive" really indicate? I thought it is like "there is data left on in the system" -> flush it to the database.

Comment: No, isActive just means there is a transaction started.  It tells nothing about what is in the persistence unit or that changes have been made. Flush will determine if there are changes and push only those changes, but should only be called if you have a purpose in mind, like you need to force statements to the database in order to catch optimistic lock or constraint issues in your code rather than waiting until the transaction commits.

Comment: thank you. My usage of the flush() method is to write the current entities to the database in order to free the memory. In my scenario it is just a import to the database. No need to maintain the entities any longer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the javadoc of the method **flush** of eclipselink's **EntityManager** class:

https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush()

> void flush()
>   Synchronize the persistence context to the underlying database.
>   Throws:
>   TransactionRequiredException - if there is no transaction or if the entity manager has not been joined to the current transaction
>   PersistenceException - if the flush fails

So yes it looks like you need to check, other ways you might get an exception of type "TransactionRequiredException"